# XML node Latest timestamp C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, duplicates, xelement

I need to only print the same employee once and check if its the latest timestamp. I need employee id only once but the latest timestamp of it.

This is my result so far, printing same id with different timestamps (example):

```
1 2015-03-16T21:32:30
1 2015-03-16T21:33:30
2 2015-03-16T21:32:30
3 2015-03-16T21:32:30
2 2015-03-16T21:33:30
```

This is what my code looks like right now.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement xelement = XElement.Load("data.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> employees = xelement.Elements();
            Console.WriteLine("List of Employee and latest timestamp:");
            foreach (var employee in employees)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} has Employee ID {1}",
                    employee.Element("Employee").Value,
                    employee.Element("ChangeTimeStamp").Value);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

To be clear i would like my result to be :

```
1 2015-03-16T21:33:30
2 2015-03-16T21:33:30
3 2015-03-16T21:32:30
```

Comment: Looks like you are just iterating through the eployees. Have you tried anything for solving your problem? Where are you experiencing trouble?

Comment: Well i dont know how i could compare the timestamps to eachother?

Comment: @Girre, can you provide a sample Xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group your employee nodes by the value of `Employee` element like this:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("data.xml");
var employees = xelement.Elements()
            .Select(e => new 
            {
                Name = e.Element("Employee").Value,
                ChangeTimestamp = DateTime.Parse(e.Element("ChangeTimestamp").Value)
            })
            .GroupBy(e => e.Name)
            .Select( g => new 
            {
                Name = g.Key,
                ChangeTimestamp = g.Max(e => e.ChangeTimestamp)
            });
```

Now, when you iterate you should have the proper values

```
foreach(var employee in employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", employee.Name, employee.ChangeTimestamp);
}
```

**Edit I**

To remove the other elements except the ones with the last version you should filter them and remove each one from their parent. The code should look something like this:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("data.xml");
xelement.Elements()
    .GroupBy(e => e.Element("Employee").Value)
    .SelectMany(g =>
    {
        var maxDate = g.Max( e => DateTime.Parse(e.Element("ChangeTimestamp").Value));
        return g.Where(e => DateTime.Parse(e.Element("ChangeTimestamp").Value) != maxDate);
    })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(e=>e.Remove());
```

This, of course is not the optimal solution but it gives you a hint in the right direction. Adjust it to fit your needs.

**Edit II**

The file from the paste bin has 3 different employees and not 3 different `ChangeTimestamp`s for one single employee. I've tried the following snippet and it worked:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"path");
doc.Root.Elements("Employee")
    .GroupBy(e => e.Element("Employee").Value)
    .SelectMany(g=>
    {
        return g.OrderByDescending(e => DateTime.Parse(e.Element("ChangeTimeStamp").Value))
            .Skip(1);
    })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(e=>e.Remove());
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove elements who is not the latest verision of that id from the xml file? And then save the xml file again?

Comment: This is great but it isnt overwriting the current xml file and saves.

Comment: I tried this "xelement.Save("data.xml");" but i suppose it isnt correct since it aint working :)

Comment: It will not overwrite the file because the data is in memory. Try saving it with another name and see if the data suits you.

Comment: And how do i do that? xelement.save(data1.xml)?

Comment: Yes. That should do it.

Comment: Ive been looking into the xml file now and it seem like all the elements i wanted to remove have got value of the first employee instead. I want to remove full parent if timestamp is outdated.

Comment: @Girre, remove the parent of the element instead of the element itself.

Comment: Thats what ive been trying to do.. but i dont know how i will do that.

Comment: Right now the xml files are identical i checked in compare function notepad++

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in your code and see what the values are. As I said, this is just a hint in the right direction. I cannot guess why it is not working. I don not even know how the xml looks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put your data in a `Dictionary<int, DateTime>` since you want only one entry for each employee.

```
Dictionary<int, DateTime> employeeList = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();

foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    int employeeId = employee.Element("Employee").Value;
    DateTime employeeDate;

    bool dateOk = DateTime.TryParse(employee.Element("ChangeTimeStamp").Value, employeeDate);

    if (dateOk) 
    {
        if (employeeList.ContainsKey(employeeId))
        {
            if (employeeList[employeeId].Value.CompareTo(employeeDate) < 0)
            {
                employeeList[employeeId].Value = employeeDate;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            employeeList.Add(employeeId, employeeDate);
        }
    }
}
```

After that you have one entry for every employee with the most current date.